# Perl - Mail::Sendmail encoding issue

Tags: perl, email, encoding, ascii, sendmail

I am trying to send mail with a message that has some non ascii characters like ΓÇô

Mail::Sendmail fails with the error "Wide character in subroutine entry at C:/Perl64/site/lib/Mail/Sendmail.pm line 237"

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's [a nice article](http://www.perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=683941) on this very problem at PerlMonks. In short, you need to encode the data you send. An example from the aforementioned article:

```
use Encode;

my $bytes = encode('utf8', $input);
email( {
  ...
  charset => 'utf8',
  _text => $bytes,
}) ...
```